# How to get Row data from a clickable column in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorry if this question is posted!!!

but i have a table with the button at the last column

i can make a row clickable and i can fetch the data of the row as shown in the code below

**but i want to get the data of the row by clicking the click button not by clicking the row**
anyone can help will be appreciated
Thank You!!!!

here is the table

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("fname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("lname").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("age").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
  };
}
```

```css
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

table tr:not(:first-child):hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br><br>

<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Button</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN1</td>
        <td>LN1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN2</td>
        <td>LN2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN3</td>
        <td>LN3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN4</td>
        <td>LN4</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN5</td>
        <td>LN5</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the *tr* element you should attach the event to the corresponding *button*. Also, you should start the loop from 1 to ignore the first *tr* (table header) element. You also have to find the closest *tr* element to find the cells to assign the text:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("fname").value = this.closest('tr').cells[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("lname").value = this.closest('tr').cells[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("age").value = this.closest('tr').cells[2].innerHTML;
  };
}
```

```css
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

table tr:not(:first-child):hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br><br>

<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Button</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN1</td>
        <td>LN1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN2</td>
        <td>LN2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN3</td>
        <td>LN3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN4</td>
        <td>LN4</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>FN5</td>
        <td>LN5</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td> <button>CLick</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add event handler to cell index 3 `table.rows[i].cells[3]` and use `this.parentNode.cells` to access cell

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                 table.rows[i].cells[3].onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById("fname").value = this.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("lname").value = this.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("age").value = this.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
             };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Display Selected HTML Table TR Values In Input Text</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        table tr:not(:first-child) {
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        table tr:not(:first-child):hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br><br>

    <table id="table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>FN1</td>
            <td>LN1</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><button>Click</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>FN2</td>
            <td>LN2</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td><button>Click</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>FN3</td>
            <td>LN3</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td><button>Click</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>FN4</td>
            <td>LN4</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td><button>Click</button></td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>FN5</td>
            <td>LN5</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td><button>Click</button></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <script>

        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
                    
         for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                 table.rows[i].cells[3].onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById("fname").value = this.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("lname").value = this.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("age").value = this.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
             };
   }  
    </script> 

</body>

</html>
```